# Freebase MQL query retrieving inconsistent results

Tags: freebase

When I run this query in the freebase query builder

```
[{
  "/type/object/id": "/en/michael_jackson",
  "/type/object/name": null,
  "/type/object/type": "/music/artist",
  "/music/artist/album": [{
    "id":            null,
    "name":          [],
    "release_type!=": "Single",
    "/music/album/primary_release": [{
      "name":       null,
      "track_list": [{name:null}]
    }]
  }]
}];​
```

I get back the proper results, with album and track listing but if  change the query to

```
[{
  "/type/object/id": "/en/carly_rae_jepsen",
  "/type/object/name": null,
  "/type/object/type": "/music/artist",
  "/music/artist/album": [{
    "id":            null,
    "name":          [],
    "release_type!=": "Single",
    "/music/album/primary_release": [{
      "name":       null,
      "track_list": [{name:null}]
    }]
  }]
}];​
```

I dont get back anything. You can try both of these queries at http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor. Can somebody point out what am I doing wrong? Both of these are artist, so I should get back abum and track listing for Carly Rae Jepsen also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all albums have a primary release recorded.  Unless you really care about this, I'd loosen your constraints and use a query like [this](http://tinyurl.com/cxqtccz):

```
[{
  "id": "/en/carly_rae_jepsen",
  "name": null,
  "type": "/music/artist",
  "/music/artist/album": [{
    "id":            null,
    "name":          null,
    "release_type!=": "Single",
    "/music/album/releases": [{
      "name":       null,
      "track_list": [{"name":null}]
    }]
  }]
}]​
```

Some other tweaks to the query:

- the last "name" wasn't quoted
- queries aren't terminated by a semicolon
- /type/object is the default and can be omitted, similarly with properties associated with the most recently specified type
- name is a single valued property, so one uses null as opposed to []

If you want the primary release if available, but not have it constrain your query, you can use "optional":true.  You could get even fancier by sorting all releases by release date and only taking the first one (on the assumption that that's got a good chance of being the primary release).

The resulting query would look like [this](http://tinyurl.com/cfk53k2):

```
[{
  "id":   "/en/carly_rae_jepsen",
  "name": null,
  "type": "/music/artist",
  "album": [{
    "id":            null,
    "name":          [],
    "release_type!=": "Single",
    "primary_release": [{
      "optional": true,
      "name":     null,
      "track_list": [{
        "name": null
      }]
    }],
    "releases": [{
      "name":         null,
      "track_list": [{
        "name": null
      }],
      "release_date": null,
      "sort":         "release_date",
      "limit":        1
    }]
  }]
}]​
```